# Remove fading edes from top and bottom of expandableListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working on expandableListView, and it is showing header and footer divider in child view

[image]

As you can see, it is showing a divider before chapter-2 and after chapter-7

I have added this code in xml:

```
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
```

but its not working.

Comment: I think they are listitem **separators** instead of Headers and Footers.

Comment: But I just want to hide the seprators at the top and bottom. If am using a listview, then these using these options hide the header and the footer seprator, but not in expandableListview.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand well. Are you talking about those kind of shadows it adds after the header and before the footer? The so called "fading edges"?